# Работа метода onNetworkConnectionChanged

Tags: android, методы

Столкнулся с проблемой - при проверке наличия соединения выполняется метод onNetworkConnectionChanged в любом из activity приложения. Ожидалось, что метод сработает только в текущем активити. Как реализовать?

Код:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // register connection status listener
        MyApplication.getInstance().setConnectivityListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Callback will be triggered when there is change in
     * network connection
     */
    @Override
    public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
        dialog.setMessage("onNetworkConnectionChanged started");
        new RequestTask().execute("http://www.example.net/test/request.php");
    }
```

Comment: Если метод `setConnectivityListener(...)` перезаписывает листнер, то должно вызываться только в одном активити. Покажите код этого метода. Для чистоты эксперимента, можете сетить `null` в `onPause(...)`.

Comment: а слушатель убиваете?

Comment: Как это можно сделать? return`ом ?